# Handle cypress new tab with typescript

Tags: typescript, cypress, sinon, stub

I am new to Cypress and I am trying to handle the usage of new application tabs.

I have a [button without a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83LmP.png)

When clicking on this button, a new tab is opened with a random id in the URL (eg. '/ticket/{some-id}')

I have a Cypress test project with typescript.
I am trying to take that link of the new tab and use it in the current test runner browser.

I have followed the examples from https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowopen but I have some errors:

1. Error for **.wrappedMethod**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq2Yq.png : *Property 'wrappedMethod' does not exist on type '((url?: string | URL, target?: string, features?: string) => Window) & ((url?: string | URL, target?: string, features?: string) => Window)'.*
2. Error for **.as('open')**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3u2b.png : *Property 'as' does not exist on type 'SinonStub<any[], any>'.*

**Note: This error is happening only for .ts files. The method works for .js file. But I need to have the tests in typescript**

Could someone please help me understand if I need some specific dependencies/ configuration to make it work?

This is my code:
tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "cypress.config.ts.test"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "E2E test suite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Cypress e2e tests",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "format": "prettier . --write"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cspell/eslint-plugin": "^8.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "faker": "^6.6.6",
    "npx": "^10.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@bahmutov/cy-api": "^2.2.6",
    "@cypress/puppeteer": "^0.1.3",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.4.1",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^10.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.0",
    "chai": "^5.0.3",
    "cypress": "^13.7.0",
    "cypress-await": "^1.6.2",
    "cypress-codegen": "^2.0.0",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

test.cy.ts class:

```
import { parkingLotAccessPage } from '../../support/pageObjects/pageElements/parkingLot/parking-lot-access.page';

describe('Parking Lot Access', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
  });

  it('should successfully access parking lot while still available spaces', function () {
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.stub(win, 'open')
        .callsFake((url, target) => {
          expect(target).to.be.undefined;
          return win.open.wrappedMethod.call(win, url, '_self');
        })
        .as('open');
    });
    parkingLotAccessPage.openBarrierButton().click();
  });
});
```

parkingLotAccessPage.page.ts Page Object:

```
class ParkingLotAccessPage {
  private elements = {
    openBarrierButton: () => cy.get('.barrier-button'),
  };

  get openBarrierButton() {
    return this.elements.openBarrierButton;
  }
}

export const parkingLotAccessPage = new ParkingLotAccessPage();
```

cypress.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
require('dotenv').config();

export default defineConfig({
  screenshotOnRunFailure: false,
  video: false,
  defaultCommandTimeout: 10000,

  retries: {
    runMode: 2
  },

  env: {
    apiUrl: process.env.BASE_API ?? 'http://localhost:8080',

    userPassword: process.env.USER_PASSWORD,
    userName: process.env.USER_NAME,

    adminPassword: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    adminUserName: process.env.ADMIN_NAME
  },

  e2e: {
    baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL ?? 'http://localhost:3000',
    supportFile: 'cypress/support/e2e.ts'
  }
});
```

Comment: Please include the Cypress code you're running into issues with. Even with your screenshots, the error modals cover up the majority of your code. Please include the code as text and not as screenshots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @agoff I've now updated the description with the code. Please let me know if I should add any other information. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `cy.stub()` command uses Sinon under the hood, so the first thing you need is the [sinon types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sinon):

```js
npm install --save @types/sinon
```

and add in **tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress", "node", "@types/sinon/index.d.ts"]
```

Then in the test you can solve #1 wrappedMethod with a cast, and #2 `.as()` by reversing the chaining order

```js
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open')
    .as('open')
    .callsFake((url, target) => {
      expect(target).to.be.undefined;
      return (win.open as sinon.SinonStub).wrappedMethod.call(win, url, '_self')
    })
})
```

---

#### A Reproducible Example

Here is the Cypress/Typescript test with the code to trigger `window.open` made generic (will work without the app)

```js
cy.window().then(win => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open')
    .as('open')
    .callsFake((url, target) => {
      expect(target).to.be.undefined
      return (win.open as sinon.SinonStub).wrappedMethod.call(win, url, '_self')
    })
})

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.open('https://example.com')
})

cy.get('@open')
  .should('have.been.calledOnceWithExactly', 'https://example.com')
```

[image]